# Angular Material md-sidenav Scrolls page behind the backdrop to Top

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I have implemented an Angular Material's md-sidenav in my application. But the problem I'm facing is if I open my md-sidenav on click of a button which is present on the bottom of the page. Once the md-sidenav opens it makes the main page behind the backdrop to scroll all the way to top.

How to avoid this functionality?

Would be waiting for the suggestions

Thank you

Comment: I am not facing any issues as you are , please refer this

http://codepen.io/Rishii/full/zqPyvB/

Comment: @Rishab777 I could see your codepen not working correctly. Can you check on it once again?

Comment: I have updated the codepen,please have a look at it.